Does this box look good for a ceiling fan?
I want to convert from a regular ceiling light to a ceiling fan. Took the light off and found this electrical box. It's metal, feels solid when I try to move it around and looks to be fastened with 2 vertical screws.
Would this look alright for a ceiling fan, how else should I check if this can support the weight?


it is not good for fan

What is the make and model of the fan you installed? Did it have a wireless remote which controls both the fan and a light kit under the fan? At first I was puzzled by the presence of the tabs with unthreaded holes larger than the machine screws, but on reflection this helps to guide the screws to the threaded locations and the tabs could, for some fan bracket types, act as stops for the fan bracket to press onto.

I have done some research and this may well be a fan rated box.  First look in the box to see if it shows a fan rating.  That should tell you for sure.
Check if the holes in the bottom of the box are threaded or have threaded nuts captured behind (Bluelines).  If you can find machine screws long enough to go through the mounting tangs, (red lines) and thread into the bottom of the box, you can mount a fan. There would be no other logical reason to need such stout screws to mount a fixture.
Be sure the box itself is firmly mounted to a joist or truss cord. (The screws shown are common for fan boxes.)


Thank you. The box felt pretty rock solid so I installed the fan on it. I found an old label which said Ceiling Fan / Light fixture rated.
There were machine screws from the old light figure which like you said that went through the red holes into the blue holes.

Unscrewing the Phillips-head hex screws could also let you remove the box and reveal what kind of supporting structure is above it.

The problem with unscrewing the Phillips head screws all the way is that they might not go back in properly. I would assume the box was installed by a professional electrician and done properly. This box appears to be secured to a support above. This could be either a wooden member or a metal bar. OP could try to wiggle the box to determine if it is supported above rather than one one side only as light weight ceiling boxes are. If it seems solid, I would not remove or even loosen the Phillips screws. This is assuming that the fan to be installed is standard and not some giant very heavy fan.

What is the make and model of the fan you installed? Did it have a wireless remote which controls both the fan and a light kit under the fan?

Yes it had a remote, however I installed the light hardwired to a separate light switch. If you look in my photo, there is a secondary line (black) which was capped off previously.
